# Web API - Only 1 Action Per HTTP Verb/Parameter Combination?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm quite familiar with MVC, but fairly new to WebAPI and I've run into a confusing issue.

I have a controller (Which inherits from ApiController) called "DummyController" and it's got the 5 default scaffolded methods for get,post,put and delete (2 for get), and I've addd my own method at the bottom called "FindDummyObjects()" which I've decorated with the [HttpGet] attribute.

when I navigate to "api/dummy" or "api/dummy/get", I get the default result fo the 2 string objects ("value1" and "value2").
However, when I navigate to "api/dummy/FindDummyObjects", it complains that "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id'".

This means that it's not pointing to my Action at all (As it is parameterless), so it's probably pointing to the default "Get(int id)" action.

When I comment out all actions except my own, I get the results I expect.

So my question is this, with WebAPI, is it only possible to have 1 action per http verb with a certain set of parameters, regardless of whether the action's names differ?

For example, it seems as though it will not be possible for me to 10 different http GET actions in a single controller, unless they all have different parameters and use the action name "Get" (Unless I do some custom routing I suppose).

Is that correct?

Code:
            // GET api/dummy
        public  IEnumerable Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

```
    // GET api/dummy/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST api/dummy
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // PUT api/dummy/5
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE api/dummy/5
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Models.DummyObject> FindDummyObjects()
    {
        IList<Models.DummyObject> myDummyList = new List<Models.DummyObject>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Models.DummyObject dumObj = new Models.DummyObject();
            dumObj.ObjectId = i;
            dumObj.ObjectName = string.Empty;

            myDummyList.Add(dumObj);
        }

        return myDummyList;
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't sound like correct behavior.  If the names of the actions differ, then they're entirely different routes and the framework should easily determine which one is which.  Can you show the actual code instead of just describing it?

Comment: just added the code as requested

Comment: Why do you have a `FindDummyObjects` method? You don't seem to be respecting the RESTful conventions. What you need is an `IEnumerable<Models.DummyObject> Get()` method on your `DummiesController`. When you are doing RESTful routing **ALWAYS** think in terms of resources.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov I'm just experimenting at the moment.  I know that's how I *could* get it to work, but I'm more interested in why the implementation I've described **doesn't** work.

Comment: It doesn't work because out-of-the-box, ASP.NET Web API relies on standard RESTful routing. It expects that if some developer has chosen this framework he probably would like to use REST as convention. If he wants to violate those conventions then he will need to go the hard way and modify his routes, etc... Or maybe just use some RPC framework such as WCF in which there are not resources and the HTTP verb is not dominant.

Comment: Does your route actually have the {action} parameter in it?  The default Web API route doesn't include the {action} parameter, if you want to do action selection based on it, then you need to include it.

Comment: yes it contains the action parameter.  It looks like the normal mvc route config setup

Comment: You can define custom routes in your WebApiConfig class to handle this, but I agree with the comment above. If you truly have something that is a custom action, put it on a Controller, not ApiController.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov  REST has absolutely nothing to say about how to map URIs to controllers.  A controller could implement one resource or 50.  Web API has no opinion on whether you decide to respect the REST constraints or not.  Web API only cares about HTTP.

Comment: @DarrelMiller, I completely agree with you that REST is not saying how to map URIs to controllers. REST is saying how to map HTTP verbs to resources though. And in ASP.NET Web API the resources are the controllers.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Mapping controllers is resources is one way to use Web API.  It's not the only way though.  Early prototypes of Web API actually had a Resource class but it was too opinionated to stay in the core.

Comment: @DarrelMiller, that's one of the reasons why I consider ASP.NET Web API as not very well architected framework and I personally use ServiceStack.NET. Although I must agree with you that Microsoft did a very good progress with v2 in Web API by introducing attribute based routing. They are getting closer to how real REST frameworks such as ServiceStack must look like. They are just missing to make messages as the core of the framework to make it completely right.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov  ServiceStack seems like an excellent implementation of a message based framework.  However, from what I have seen, it violates the REST self-descriptive constraint and provides no support for the hypermedia constraint.  It is certainly far from what I would consider a "real REST framework".

Comment: @DarrelMiller, stating that ServiceStack is *certainly far from what I would consider a "real REST framework"* is like saying that you have only *seen* or *heard* of ServiceStack, not actually used it in a real application :-)

Comment: @DarinDimitrov That's like saying because I've never ridden a dolphin I can't possibly state that it is not a fish.  Have you read this? http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven  ServiceStack fails to meet most of these rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web API routing has quite a few holes (I'm being polite), you happened to hit on one.  This is one of the reasons that they introduced Attribute Routing in Web API2.  You might want to try that as it is quite a bit more flexible.